# Show that $h(z)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{1-tz}dt$ is analytic in a nbh. of zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> Consider the function
>   $$h(z)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{1-tz}dt$$
>   whenever the integral exists, $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $h$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the origin and calculate the power series expansion of $h$ centered around the origin.

I have difficulties with this problem. I tried to show that its complex derivative exists but getting nowhere. Any tips?

Comment: you have an analytic integrand around zero, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $g(z,t)$ is  continuous as a function of $z$ and $t$ in some region $U \times V \subseteq \mathbb C^2$ and analytic in $z$ there, then $\oint_\Gamma g(z,t)\; dt$ is analytic in $U$.  This can be seen by approximating the integral as a limit of Riemann sums.

To get the power series, expand the integrand in a geometric series about $z=0$ and integrate term-by-term.

Comment: Ok thats was easy knowing that theorem!! Thanks